# Passing input object to ConvertTo-Html

Tags: powershell

Why is the output of following code blocks different? The object that ConvertTo-Html cmdlet takes as input is not the same in both cases? The output of code block 1 is what I was expecting.

Code 1:

```
$psdrive = Get-PSDrive
$psdrive | ConvertTo-Html
```

Code 2:

```
$psdrive = Get-PSDrive
ConvertTo-Html -InputObject $psdrive
```

Here the outputs.

Output 1:

```
 ...
     <tr>
        <th>Used</th>
        <th>Free</th>
        <th>CurrentLocation</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Provider</th>
        <th>Root</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>MaximumSize</th>
        <th>Credential</th>
        <th>DisplayRoot</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Alias</td>
        <td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Drive that contains a view of the aliases stored in a session state</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>72876965888</td>
        <td>12914372608</td>
        <td>Windows\system32</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem</td>
        <td>C:\</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  ...
```

Output 2:

```
   ...
      <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th>LongLength</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>SyncRoot</th>
        <th>IsReadOnly</th>
        <th>IsFixedSize</th>
        <th>IsSynchronized</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>System.Object[]</td>
        <td>False</td>
        <td>True</td>
        <td>False</td>
    </tr>
</table>
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-5.1#one-at-a-time-processing) behaves.

`Get-PsDrive` will return an **array** (if there is more than one drive).

```
$psdrive.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

By *piping* `$psdive` (which should be called `$psdrives`, plural), you pass *every single item* of the array to `ConvertTo-Html`, so they will be formatted properly.

By passing the actual array as `-InputObject` it will convert *the array itself* into HTML, that's why you see the array members such as `Count`, `Length` etc. You would get the same result if you passed an empty array: `ConvertTo-Html -InputObject @()`

You can easily see that behavior, check this out:

```
# will return the members of the drives (Root, MaximumSize, ...)
$psdrive | Get-Member

# will return the members of the array that contains the drives (Add, Count, ...)
Get-Member -InputObject $psdrive
```

**Conclusion:** The first version, using the pipeline, is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was missing how the pipeline behaves. This has been helpful too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-5.1#one-at-a-time-processing

Comment: @anderZubi Yes that's the right section. I updated the link in my answer.